# encrypt password in putty session

Tags: encryption, passwords

how to encrypt the username & password in putty.i used the below command:
start putty.exe -load script -ssh ipaddress  -l username -pw Password -m commands.txt

to access my device.

Comment: SSH is 'Secure shell'. It automatically encrypts and sends the password and username. There is no need for further encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Logging in with SSH private key in windows](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/logging-in-with-an-ssh-private-key-on-windows/)

In this link, they’re demonstrating how to load a private key into PuTTY. You’ll need two pieces of software to complete this task:

1. PuTTY - Client to for managing SSH sessions
2. PuTTYgen - Tool for managing and creating SSH key pairs

This way you no need to pass the password explicitly on the command line.

As an alternate method, if you install posh-git in your windows you could use ssh command from the powershell prompt with ssh config file pointing to the identity key. [Refer Link](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/)